# Prepositions 'in' or 'of' for referring to a population of a country

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was wondering about these prepositions *in* and *of*. Actually I was making an assignment in Spanish and I came across this problem and I translated it in English but I am still puzzled as to what the difference is in:

 "The population of America..." and
 "The population in America..."

when do you use each or is there no difference at all? thank you in advance.

Comment: Migrate to ELL?

Answer (score 6):

"The population *of* America . . ." sounds as if it should be followed by "is 300,000,000" or "was 200,000,000 in 1913," or "has increased blank percent in the last 50 years." The preposition *of* seems to be go best with the population as a whole, not with the various segments within that population.

On the other hand, "The population *in* America . . ." sounds as if it should be followed by any of the following:  1) "is comprised of 20 percent Black; 53 percent white; 15 percent Hispanic," etc.; 2) "has grown by 128 percent since 1913"; 3) "[comma] compared to the next-most populous nation in the world, is only 20 million fewer people"; or 4) "in the over-85 age-group has grown significantly in the last decade, from 12 percent of the total population to 18 percent of the total population."

The preposition *in* seems to work best when addressing the various segments (plural) within the population (see number 1 above), or *a* segment--as in a rate, percent or percentage--that represents an increase or decrease (see numbers 2, 3, and 4 above).

There may be a few exceptions to the above, but the information on the whole is likely accurate.

Comment: I came to this same conclusion. "of" is used to give a general information, thus one fact but, if you are going to elaborate deeper then, you use "in". thanks

Comment: @Derrick - You misunderstand.  "Of" refers to the entire area, while "in" is qualifying whatever specific segment of the population is being counted.

Comment: By the way, the population of America is around one billion.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, and the number of housecats I currently have living in my humble abode is 14,000,000. You can't imagine how much we spend on cat litter! We have it delivered by dump truck. Don

Comment: (The population of the *United States* of America is around 300 million.   There's more to America than just the United States.)

Comment: @HotLicks: You mean the population in "North America," "Central America," and "South America" combined?

Comment: @rhetorician - Yep, "America" is North, Central, and South America.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only time you'd use "in" in such a case is if you were using "population" in its meaning of "a group of people" that you wanted to place geographically, e.g.:

- Among Spanish speakers, *the population in America* is the most likely to use "America" to refer to the United States of America.

...or if, for some reason, you wanted to (confusingly) use "population" to mean "the action of populating an area" you could also say something like:

- Population in America will exceed emigration for the foreseeable future.

If you are nominating the statistic called "population" (i.e. how many people there are), which you seem to be in your examples, then "of" will serve you better every time, as in:

- The population *of* America is 309 million.
- The population *of* America was 97 million in 1913.
- The population *of* America is 72% white, 12% black, 16% Hispanic, etc.
- The population *of* America has grown 317% since 1913.
- The population *of* America, compared with the next-most populous nation in the world, is 78 million more people.